# Why is \tl_if_in:VnTF giving a different answer depending on where it is?

Tags: expl3, l3prop

I'm trying to build a simple replacements dictionary using a `prop` structure of replacements `old=new`.  When I'm mapping through the `prop`, I don't find any replacements.  When I'm not (i.e., hardcoding), I do.  What's going on here?

#### MWE

```
\nonstopmode
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\prop_put:Nnn \l_tmpa_prop {sean} {patrick}
\msg_term:n {resolving}

\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {hello,~sean}
\prop_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_prop
{
  \tl_show:N \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_show:n {#1}
  \tl_if_in:VnTF \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
    { \msg_term:n {`#1'~found~in~`\l_tmpa_tl'} }
    { \msg_term:n {`#1'~not~found~in~`\l_tmpa_tl'} }
}

\msg_term:n {contrived}
\tl_show:N \l_tmpa_tl
\tl_show:n {sean}
\tl_if_in:VnTF \l_tmpa_tl {sean}
  { \msg_term:n {oh,~yes~it~is!} }
  { \msg_term:n {nope} }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
hello
\end{document}
```

#### Output

```
* resolving
*************************************************
> \l_tmpa_tl=hello, sean.
<recently read> }

l.18     }

> sean.
<recently read> }

l.18     }

*************************************************
* `sean' not found in `hello, sean'
*************************************************
*************************************************
* contrived
*************************************************
> \l_tmpa_tl=hello, sean.
<recently read> }

l.21     \tl_show:N \l_tmpa_tl

> sean.
<recently read> }

l.22     \tl_show:n {sean}

*************************************************
* oh, yes it is!
```

Comment: Are you sure that `\l_tmpa_tl` is still the same you expect it to be? And shouldn't it be `\tl_if_in:VnTF {#2} ...`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer See the `contrived` example; it certainly looks to me like each piece of state is the same.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer concerning `#2` vs `{#2}`: no, I don't think so (though I did try that). It's my understanding that capital-letter arguments are given without braces (e.g. `\tl_new:N \l_my_tl`).

Comment: Yes, I forgot about that convention

Answer (score 2):

What you are forgetting here is category codes: yes, the two token lists contain the same characters, but if you use `\tl_show_analysis:N` you can see that they have different catcodes. This is because keys are detokenized: as the documentation says

> The ⟨keys⟩ are compared on a string basis, using the same method as
>   `\str_if_eq:nn`.

(We could perhaps make it explicit that they are detokenized.)

If you want to replace the value in a prop by a new one, the correct approach is to use `\prop_put:Nnn`, which will as-described replace the stored value with a new one when the key is the same.

Comment: Note I'm not trying to replace values in a property list – I'm trying to replace values in a token list based on a property list. For example, a prop list of `{{sean}={patrick}}` will turn `\l_tmpa_tl={hello,~sean}` into `{hello,~patrick}`. I'll look into the catcode stuff :-)

Comment: It sounds like a `\str_if_in_p:nn` fits the bill exactly, but sadly it does not exist (yet?) :-(